# Can this jQuery/AJAX code be shortened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code which sets input values using jQuery/AJAX. Can the repetition of the code be shortened in anyway? It's mainly the AJAX requests I'd like shortened. It doesn't seem right to be making so many AJAX requests but despite my research I can't seem to find a way to improve things.

```
// set property defaults
var list_select_id = 'tenancy_property';
var initial_target = 'Please Select a Property First';
var initial_target_html_property = '<option value="">Please Select a Property First</option>';

//$('#tenancy_fixed_term').val(initial_target);
$('#tenancy_furnished').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_rent_amount').val(initial_target);
$('#tenancy_letting_service').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_tenant_find_fee_type').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_management_fee_type').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_gas').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_electricity').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_water').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_oil').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_telephone').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_broadband').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_tv_licence').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_sat_cable_tv').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_council_tax').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_service_charge').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_ground_rent').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_pets').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_smoking').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_deposit_amount').val(initial_target);
$('#tenancy_tenant_find_fee').val(initial_target);
$('#tenancy_management_fee').val(initial_target);

$('#'+list_select_id).change(function(e) {

var selectvalue = $(this).val();

//$('#tenancy_fixed_term').val('Loading...');
$('#tenancy_furnished').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_rent_amount').val('Loading...');
$('#tenancy_letting_service').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_tenant_find_fee_type').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_management_fee_type').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_gas').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_electricity').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_water').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_oil').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_telephone').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_broadband').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_tv_licence').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_sat_cable_tv').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_council_tax').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_service_charge').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_ground_rent').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_pets').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_smoking').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
$('#tenancy_deposit_amount').val('Loading...');
$('#tenancy_tenant_find_fee').val('Loading...');
$('#tenancy_management_fee').val('Loading...');

if (selectvalue == "" || !selectvalue || selectvalue.length === 0) {

//$('#tenancy_fixed_term').val(initial_target);
$('#tenancy_furnished').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_rent_amount').val(initial_target);
$('#tenancy_letting_service').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_tenant_find_fee_type').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_management_fee_type').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_gas').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_electricity').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_water').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_oil').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_telephone').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_broadband').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_tv_licence').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_sat_cable_tv').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_council_tax').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_service_charge').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_ground_rent').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_pets').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_smoking').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_deposit_amount').val(initial_target);
$('#tenancy_tenant_find_fee').val(initial_target);
$('#tenancy_management_fee').val(initial_target);

} else {    

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET      
//$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_fixed_term',
//success: function(output) {
//$('#tenancy_fixed_term').val(output);
//},            
//error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
//alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
//}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_furnished',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_furnished').html(output);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET      
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_rent_amount',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_rent_amount').val(output);
},          
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_letting_service',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_letting_service').html(output);
$('#tenancy_letting_service').change();
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_tenant_find_fee_type',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_tenant_find_fee_type').html(output);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_management_fee_type',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_management_fee_type').html(output);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_gas',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_gas').html(output);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_electricity',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_electricity').html(output);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_water',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_water').html(output);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_oil',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_oil').html(output);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_telephone',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_telephone').html(output);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_broadband',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_broadband').html(output);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_tv_licence',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_tv_licence').html(output);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_sat_cable_tv',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_sat_cable_tv').html(output);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_council_tax',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_council_tax').html(output);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_service_charge',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_service_charge').html(output);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_ground_rent',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_ground_rent').html(output);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_pets',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_pets').html(output);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_smoking',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_smoking').html(output);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET      
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_deposit_amount',
success: function(output) {

if (output!='0.00') {
$('#tenancy_deposit_amount').val(output);
$("#tenancy_deposit_required").val('1');

$('tr[id=tenancy_deposit_amount_tr], tr[id=tenancy_deposit_protection_responsible_tr], tr[id=tenancy_deposit_protection_scheme_tr]').css({
            'display': 'table-row'
            });
    $('fieldset[id=deposit_contributors_all]').css({
            'display': 'block'
            });

}
},          
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET      
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_tenant_find_fee',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_tenant_find_fee').val(output);
},          
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

//Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET      
$.ajax({url: '../ajax/tenancy_defaults.php?property_id='+selectvalue+'&request=tenancy_management_fee',
success: function(output) {
$('#tenancy_management_fee').val(output);
},          
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
}});

}

});
```

Comment: Working code that you want improvements on should be posted in http://codereview.stackexchange.com, not here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry, is there a way I can migrate it?

Comment: Mods can migrate it.  You could copy the content to a new question over there, then delete this one.

Comment: Mod can you delete this question. I have posted it on Code Review but it won't let me delete because of the answers.

Comment: @MichaelLB mods don't get notified for every comment out there - use the "flag" link, and enter a custom flag reason to contact a moderator. I think the best would be to leave it here, and [edit] to include a link to the cross-post, on Code Review to link here, and here to link to the CR post.

Comment: @MichaelLB I recommend you read about JQuery chaining and JQuery multiple selectors. This are the exact techniques you need to use to shorten your code. One means using multiple elements and calling one method, while the other uses one element and calls multiple methods. Both can also be used alternatively when the opportunity arises.

Comment: Discussion of this question is now over here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114788/populating-many-fields-in-a-form-using-jquery-ajax/114790

Answer (score 1):

You can select multiple elements with jquery.
The long way:

```
$('#tenancy_furnished').html(initial_target_html_property);
$('#tenancy_letting_service').html(initial_target_html_property);
```

can be concatenated:

```
$('#tenancy_letting_service,#tenancy_furnished').html(initial_target_html_property);
```

The short answer to your question is: yes.

Answer (score -1):

What if for example

```
tenancy_tenant_find_fee
```

and

```
tenancy_management_fee
```

you use a class so you can simply do something like that

```
$(".tenancyTestClass").val(value);
```

You can do the same thing for everyone element that have to be initialized with the same value.